# Could someone please help me figure out the p value of this ARIMA(p,d,q) model?

Tags: statistics, time-series, p-value

The exercise is the following:

(b) (4 points) Consider the following model
$$
\begin{array}{r}
X_t=c+X_{t-1}+\phi_1\left(X_{t-1}-X_{t-2}\right)+\phi_2\left(X_{t-2}-X_{t-3}\right) \\
+\phi_3\left(X_{t-3}-X_{t-4}\right)+Z_t,
\end{array}
$$
where $X_t$ is the population in year $t$ and $\left\{Z_t\right\} \sim \mathrm{WN}\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$. What sort of ARIMA model is this (i.e., what are $p, d$, and $q)$ ? Include an explanation.

--

I'm not sure if $p = 4$ since there is a $X_{t-4}$ , or if $p = 3$ since the phi's go up to $\phi_3$. This is the only value that I'm unsure of, since I'm pretty sure $d=1$ since the differencing is done at lag 1 and $q=0$ since there the only white noise is $Z_{t}$

Answer (score 0):

Hi: You can write your model in the following manner:

Let $Y_t = X_{t} - X_{t-1}$.

Then, the original model can be re-written as $Y_t = \phi Y_{t-1} + \phi_{2} Y_{t-2} + \phi_{3} Y_{t-3} + Z_t$.

So, this is an ARIMA(3,0,0) for $Y_t$ because there are 3 lagged $Y_t$ variables on the RHS along with the error term.

But then that can be re-written as an ARIMA(3,1,0) on $X_t$ since we differenced once.

So, the model for $X_t$ is an ARIMA(3,1,0). I hope that makes sense.

ADDENDUM: I would write it out, in terms of ARIMA parameters, as

$(1 - B) X_{t} = \mu + \phi_1 B(1-B)(X_{t}) + \phi_2 B^2 (1-B) (X_{t}) +  \phi_{3} B^3 (1-B)(X_{t})  + Z_{t} = \mu + (1-B)(\phi_{1} B + \phi_{2} B^2 + \phi_{3} B^3) X_{t} + Z_{t}$

Comment: Thanks @mark leeds !

Also, written with the backshift operator how would it be? I'm just trying to relate the equation to the ARIMA definition.

$$Y_t:=(1-B)^1 X_t$$ 

And then I'm not sure how this would be written:

$$
\phi^*(B) X_t \equiv \phi(B)(1-B)^d X_t=\theta(B) Z_t \quad\left\{Z_t\right\} \sim \mathrm{WN}\left(0, \sigma^2\right)
$$
where $\phi(z)$ and $\theta(z)$ are polynomials of degrees $3$ and $0$ respectively and $\phi(z) \neq 0$ for $|z| \leq 1$.

Comment: @Ray Robson: I added to the answer at the bottom.